# Хотелось бы получить критику на данный код

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Это использование паттерна "Фабрика", прошу помощи понять, правильно ли я его использую.

```
<?php
Class HelloFactory {
  static $config = "My";

  public static function createHello() {
    $fullNameClass = self::$config . "Hello";
    return new $fullNameClass;
  } 
}

Class CustomHello {

  public function view() {
    return "hello world!";
  }

}

Class MyHello {

  public function view() {
    return "hello everybody";
  }

}

$test = HelloFactory::createHello();

echo $test->view();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем правильно. Фабрика должна создавать любой объект. Например расширяющих один интерфейс или абстрактный класс.

```
<?php

class HelloFactory {

  static $parentClass = "Hello";

  /**
   * @param string $className
   * @return Hello
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  public static function create($className) {
    if(!class_exists($className)) {
        throw new \Exception("Класс $className не найден");
    }
    if(!in_array(self::$parentClass, class_parents($className))) {
        throw new \Exception("Класс $className не наследует абстрактный класс " . self::$parentClass);
    }
    $object = new $className();
    // делегируем конфигурацию объекта самому объекту, иначе в фабрике много лишней логики и кода
    $object->init();
    return $object;
  } 
}

abstract class Hello {
  public $message;

  // инициализация объекта
  abstract function init();

  public function view() {
    return $this->message;
  }
}

class HelloWorld extends Hello {

  public function init() {
    $this->message = 'hello world!';
  }

}

class HelloEveryBody extends Hello {

  public function init() {
    $this->message = 'hello everybody!';
  }

}

$test = HelloFactory::create('HelloWorld');
echo $test->view() . PHP_EOL;

$test2 = HelloFactory::create('HelloEveryBody');
echo $test2->view() . PHP_EOL;

// получаем исключение
$test3 = HelloFactory::create('HelloAnyBody');
echo $test3->view() . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ с вложенным кодом.

Comment: Статические методы не комильфо =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev 1. Почему? 2. Это демо код, в реальном проекте конечно можно DI юзать и фабрику создавать через сервисы

Comment: Проблемы начнуться, когда в конструктор продукта нужно будет передавать какой-то объект. Тогда либо статические свойства, либо раздутая сигнатура `HelloFactory::create` с нарушением DIP

Answer (score 1):

В данной реализации ваша фабрика может создавать только объекты класса `MyHello`, а должна создавать объекты различных классов. Посмотрите [небольшую статью](http://devacademy.ru/posts/shablonyi-proektirovaniya-v-php-fabrika/), там всё понятно написано. Напишите интерфейс, который будут реализовывать порождаемые классы и дополните описание метода `createHello()` с помощью PHPDoc и будет всё отлично.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. т.е. код создания объекта будет выглядеть приблизительно так : 
    `public static function createHello($config) { $fullNameClass = $config . "Hello"; return new $fullNameClass; } ` Вызов соответственно: `$test = HelloFactory::createHello('Custom'); echo $test->view();`

Comment: Да, всё правильно.